# A special case of Frankl's conjecture. A question about known results

Tags: co.combinatorics, conjectures

Let's recall a Frankl's conjecture.

Consider a finite family of finite sets $\mathcal{F}$, such for every pair of sets $A\in \mathcal{F}$ and $B\in\mathcal{F}$, we have $A\cup B\in\mathcal{F}$(the family $\mathcal{F}$ is said to be union closed). The conjecture says that there is an element $a\in \bigcup_{A\in\mathcal{F}}A$, so that $a\in A$ for at least $\frac{|\mathcal{F}|}{2}$ sets $A$.

Now, let's take a set $U=\{1,2,...,n\}$ and an union closed family $\mathcal{F}'\subseteq\mathcal{P}(U)$, where $\{U,\emptyset\}\cup\mathcal{P}_{n-1}(U)\subseteq\mathcal{F}'$.

> Is it known whether this case is solved?

I would like to see a proof of this specific case.

I was trying to figure it out myself by considering an induction in respect to $|U|$, but i failed.

Thank you for any help or hint.

Comment: What do you mean by $\mathcal{P}_{n-1}(U)$?

Comment: This is a set of all subsets $A\subset U$, so that $|A|=n-1$

Comment: i doubt this case is known

Comment: For $n\ge2$ there are $n+2$ sets in this family,  $n$ of them contains  $1$, and $n\ge (n+2)/2$. So this case is trivial.